# mod_rewrite redirect all traffic from a specific domain to a particular page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, referer

I want all traffic with REFERER "bad-domain.com" to go to a specific page named hole.    It doesn't seem to work at all in .htaccess so I put it in the server config.   It is a wp and all the rest of the rewrite stuff is in .htaccess -- it is pretty typical wp rewrites.

I have had various problems, once I got a redirect loop, and once I got a 400.    The current configuration exposes the entire site's root directory structure if the referer is bad-domain we can't have that so I momentarily commented it.

I think I understand everything and I know I'm very close to the answer but I don't know how to make it do exactly what I want and nothing that I don't want.

It seems like it is ignoring the .htaccess stuff if it matches these conditions.  doesn't it do serverconfig stuff first and THEN do htaccess stuff?

This is the three lines in the server config

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*xxxxxx.com.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /hole/
```

Comment: @user230016 - add `[L]` into RewriteRule ^.*$ /hole/ refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I originally had [L] there.  Took it out because I thought it might be stopping the rest of the processing.  Put it back and restarted server.  Same bad result.  Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe I'd have more luck cross posting this in server fault

Comment: Server Fault actually has less mod_rewrite content than Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure about that. Anyway, you've said that you're specifying the rules in the server configuration now. Where in the server configuration are they located (e.g. in the site's `<Directory>` entry)?